# Text next to image lightbox

Tags: css, image-gallery

I use the WP Featherlight plugin on Wordpress. I want to put the description of an artwork in the lightbox right next to the image, not underneath like it is at this moment. How can I do that?

[You can see the website here](http://gonneke.id-buro.nl/?page_id=868&lang=en).

Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Note that the website link is now broken...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the css properties of your lightbox and the corresponding `figcaption` elements.

Refer code & make the changes accordingly:

```
.gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 260px;
}

.gallery-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery-caption {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Attaching screenshot after the above changes are done:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Set your gallery container (e.g. `div#gallery-2`) to flex row.

Like this:

```
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
```

**2.** Set `figure.gallery-item` to flex and align it's text, provide a fixed width (I used 25%) so items stack in row, otherwise each item will be full width pushing the next down:

Properties:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
width: 25%;
```

**3.** Give `.gallery-caption` some breathe from image.
Properties:

```
margin-left: 5px;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response. If the user clicks on an artwork then the lightbox will open. I want the description is on the right side of the artwork. In the lightbox I want to put some more info than on the actual page. Hope this is more clear.